# Save a list of shop Items and load it in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save, load

On the below script im trying to save the ShopItemList everytime I purchase a character that happens OnShopItemBtnClicked function. I am trying to save this with playerprefs but failed. Is there a better way. I heard json is a method we can achieve this. But i dont know what json or how to use this. Can someone help me how to save and load stuff with the current shop system I have. Please I broke my head so much thinking about it dint get an answer

***Updated Code***

```
[Serializable]
public class ShopItem
{
    public Sprite CharacterImage;
    public GameObject charactersModel;
    public int Price;
    public bool isPurchased = false;
}

//
[Serializable]
public class ShopDataList
{
    public ShopItem[] ShopItemData;
}

public class Shop : MonoBehaviour
{
    ShopDataList myShopDataList = new ShopDataList();
    //public List<ShopItem> ShopItemsList;


    [Space]
    [Header("Item Template & Display")]
    GameObject ItemTemplate;
    GameObject g;
    [SerializeField] Transform ShopScrollView;
    Button buyBtn;


    GameObject getGameManager;
    GameManager GameManagerRef;



    public void SaveMyData(ShopDataList data)
    {
        string jsonString = JsonUtility.ToJson(data); // this will give you the json (i.e serialize the data)
        File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/ShopItems.json", jsonString); // this will write the json to the specified path
    }

    public ShopDataList LoadMyData(string pathToDataFile)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(pathToDataFile)) return null;

        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(pathToDataFile); // read the json file from the file system
        ShopDataList myData = JsonUtility.FromJson<ShopDataList>(jsonString); // de-serialize the data to your myData object
        return myData;
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        LoadMyData(Application.dataPath + "/ShopItems.json");

    getGameManager = GameObject.Find("GameManager");
        GameManagerRef = getGameManager.GetComponent<GameManager>();
        ItemTemplate = ShopScrollView.GetChild(0).gameObject;

        var length = myShopDataList.ShopItemData.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            g = Instantiate(ItemTemplate, ShopScrollView);
            g.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>().sprite = myShopDataList.ShopItemData[i].CharacterImage; //ShopItemsList[i].CharacterImage; //
            g.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = myShopDataList.ShopItemData[i].Price.ToString(); //ShopItemsList[i].Price.ToString(); //**
            buyBtn = g.transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Button>();
            if (myShopDataList.ShopItemData[i].isPurchased)
            {
                DisableBuyButton();
            }
            buyBtn.AddEventListener(i, OnShopItemBtnClicked);
        }
        Destroy(ItemTemplate);
    }

    public void DisableBuyButton()
    {
        buyBtn.interactable = false;
        buyBtn.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>().text = "PURCHASED";

    }



    void OnShopItemBtnClicked(int itemIndex)
    {
        if (GameManagerRef.HasEnoughCoins(myShopDataList.ShopItemData[itemIndex].Price))
        {
            //purchase Item
            GameManagerRef.UseCoins(myShopDataList.ShopItemData[itemIndex].Price);
            myShopDataList.ShopItemData[itemIndex].isPurchased = true;
            buyBtn = ShopScrollView.GetChild(itemIndex).GetChild(2).GetComponent<Button>();
            GameManagerRef.character.Add(myShopDataList.ShopItemData[itemIndex].charactersModel);
            DisableBuyButton();
            SaveMyData(myShopDataList);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("You dont have sufficient amount");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call PlayerPrefs.Save() method to actually save the stuff you've changed in PlayerPrefs.

But you are right, saving things in an external file is usually a better way to handle it. Json is just a text file with a specific syntax. To save some data to Json first you will have to create a class that will hold the data, like

```
[Serializable]
public class MyData
{
    public int level;
    public string charName;
}
```

The "Serializable" attribute is important because we will need to "Serialize" this data. Unity have a simple json serializer you can use. Here is what you will have to do:

```
public void SaveMyData(MyData data)
{
    string jsonString = JsonUtility.ToJson(data); // this will give you the json (i.e serialize the data)
    File.WriteAllText("Path/file/name.json", jsonString); // this will write the json to the specified path
}

public MyData LoadMyData(string pathToDataFile)
{
    string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(pathToDataFile); // read the json file from the file system
    MyData myData = JsonUtility.FromJson<MyData>(jsonString); // de-serialize the data to your myData object
    return myData;
}
```

this is what your json file will look like:

```
{
    "level":123,
    "charName":"My awesome character"
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks. But I dont understand how the data will be saved. Im not understanding that part. According to my script I assign gameobjects outside in inspector and onButtonClickFunction we check the money and if yes we purchase. So am i supposed to pass the saveData json function inside the buy function

Comment: Or the save data keeps saving the class of shopItem i have continously and loads and assigns value by itself. Not able to understand this part. Sorry looking into json the first time. Understood about saving and retrieving the file

Comment: Hey i have updated the question with my version of trying yours but im not able to get it working first my shop not working second there is no file being created in the dataPath. @Anton. Can you please check and tell me where im doing wrong. I have highlighted the code with name Update code. And thank you so much for the help

Comment: Hey, good job implementing it :) as far as I can tell there is only one thing you missed. In start when you load your data you need to assign it to myShopDataList. Then check if it is null. And if it is create a new instance of ShopDataList:

myShopData = LoadMyData(Application.dataPath + "/ShopItems.json");
if(myShopData == null)
{
    myShopData = new ShopDataLis();
    myShopData.ShopItemData = new List<ShopItem>();// or however you initialize your array/list
}

This should take care of initial state when there is no save file yet